# How we count only one user how much time click on link to given all links

Tags: javascript, html

How we count only one user how much time click on link to given all links and how we display the total clicked by that user if that he Complete 10 clicked on given links to open another window to accept a some text data for him and save it.

Comment: Your question is pretty vague. What elapsed time are you keeping track of? What have you tried? Please give us an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code :

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="countTenClicks()">Click 10 times to open window
</a>
<script>

    var counter = 0;
    function countTenClicks() {
        if (counter > 9) {
            window.open('http://www.google.com');
        }
        else {
            counter++;
        }

    }

</script>
```

**Edit**

```
<html>
 <head>
<title></title>
 </head>
 <body>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="countTenClicks(this)" id='link1'>Click 10 times
    to open window link1</a> <a href="javascript:void(0)"    onclick="countTenClicks(this)"
        id='link2'>Click 10 times to open window link2 </a>
<script type="text/javascript">

var link1_counter=0;
var link2_counter=0;
/*
  repeate for 10 links

   var for each link
*/
function countTenClicks(sender){

  var linkID = sender.id;
 switch(linkID)
  {
  case link1:
  if (link1_counter>9)
 {
 window.open('http://www.google.com');
 }
  else
 {
 link1_counter++;
 }
  break;
 case link1:
  if (link2_counter>9)
  {
   window.open('http://www.google.com');
  }
else
 {
 link2_counter++;
 }
  break;
/*
 repeate for 10 links
*/

default:
code to be executed if n is different from case 1 and 2
}

}

</script>
```

Comment: How we can apply more then 10 links @Mahmoud

Comment: Do you mean that you want to have 10 links if you click anyone more than 10 times it will open a web page ??

Comment: Yes That Is Right How Can I Apply. Please Visit This Site:- http://putfreeadvertise.blogspot.in/  how Can I apply this thing on my displaying images which is advertisements .........